# Can you launch a non-elevated application from a perMachine WiX package?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, uac

We have a per-machine install package built with WiX 3.9.

```
<Package InstallerVersion="405" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
```

And we are also using `WixShellExec` to launch an application from a `CustomAction` as part of the package install.

```
    <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#Application.exe]" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="LaunchApplication" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This launches our application as expected, but it launches the application with elevated permissions.

From what we have seen, it is not possible to launch the application without elevated permissions from a per-machine install package. We have tried various combinations of `Impersonate="yes|no"` and `Execute="deferred|immediate"`. We have also tried using a `FileKey` custom action directly to launch the application.

We are using a custom bootstrapper application and so cannot use the [built-in WiX UI](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html) around this functionality. Is the only way to achieve a non-elevated launch of our application to do so manually from our custom bootstrapper application?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this - it's from a reliable source:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/11/18/10468726.aspx

Comment: @diaecticus: There is no WiX code. The WiX code is in the original post that launches the elevated custom action. It's the code in that custom action that needs to be written to launch a non-elevated process.